# Android How to View Process Crash Logs on Android Device

Tags: android

My app on android device Samsung Galaxy crashes on powerup.  What are the best tools to view the crash logs?  Thanks  Also where exactly are these logs located with stacktrace? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set use a real hardware while developing. You could do this by following the documentation

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

then you can see the stacktrace by selecting the real hardware and looking at the logcat content that is present as a eclipse view just the same as you develop in emulator.

Comment: Logcat is not always available for a crash. Consider powerup.

Comment: My question is where to see the crash logs on the device.  Please respond to this.  Thanks

Comment: By using logcat you can find see all phone related logs. It is much more detailed than you think. May be I did not understand you well, may be this can help http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/

Comment: In eclipse main menu select Window > Show View > Other > Android > Devices. You will see devices view in eclipse. Then connect your phone in debug mode. Afterwards select your device (not any app, just select the device like galaxy tab) from devices view. Then you will see all logs that your device generated at that time.

Comment: How can I be connected in debug mode at that time?

Comment: Hi, After you close your phone, your phone goes from devices, so you can not see logcat, then go to devices view, start your phone, after that click on your phone when it appears during the bootup. It will show all logs during that time. I tried it and it worked. Sorry for late response, I am in Turkey and I just woke up